# Aggregation of value in GLSL loop results in 0

Tags: opengl, glsl

I'm banging my head against a wall trying to understand why this code is giving me some reasonable results with some visible colors on parts of the screen...

```
#version 130

in vec2 vTex; // must match name in vertex shader
flat in int iLayer; // must match name in fragment shader

out vec4 fragColor; // first out variable is automatically written to the screen

uniform sampler2DArray tex;
uniform sampler2DArray norm;

#define MAX_LIGHTS 4

struct Light {
    vec3 position;
    vec4 color;
    vec3 falloff;
    vec3 aim;
    float aperture;
    float aperturehardness;
};

uniform Light lights[MAX_LIGHTS];

void main()
{
    vec4 DiffuseColor = texture(tex, vec3(vTex.x, vTex.y, iLayer));
    if (DiffuseColor.a == 0)
        discard;
    vec3 NormalMap = texture(norm, vec3(vTex.x, vTex.y, iLayer)).rgb;
    NormalMap.g = 1.0 - NormalMap.g;
    vec3 FinalColor = vec3(0,0,0);

    for (int i=0; i<MAX_LIGHTS; i++)
    {
        vec3 LightDir = vec3((lights[i].position.xy - gl_FragCoord.xy) / vec2(320.0, 200.0).xy, lights[i].position.z);
        float D = length(LightDir);
        vec3 N = normalize(NormalMap * 2.0 - 1.0);
        vec3 L = normalize(LightDir);
        vec3 Diffuse = (lights[i].color.rgb * lights[i].color.a) * max(dot(N, L), 0.0);
        vec3 sd = normalize(vec3(gl_FragCoord.xy, -1.0) - lights[i].position);
        float Attenuation = smoothstep(lights[i].aperture * lights[i].aperturehardness, lights[i].aperture, dot(sd,lights[i].aim))
            / (lights[i].falloff.x + (lights[i].falloff.y*D) + (lights[i].falloff.z*D*D) ) ;
        vec3 Intensity = Diffuse * Attenuation;
        FinalColor = max(FinalColor, DiffuseColor.rgb * Intensity);
    }
    fragColor = vec4(FinalColor, DiffuseColor.a);
}
```

... but when I change `FinalColor = max(FinalColor, DiffuseColor.rgb * Intensity);` to `FinalColor = clamp(FinalColor + DiffuseColor.rgb * Intensity, vec3(0,0,0), vec3(1,1,1));` everything goes black. Is there something I don't understand about aggregation of variables in loops in GLSL, or about the `+` operator operating on vectors? By my logic, the changed code should return *more* brightness than the original code because the changed code would be adding all the values whereas the old code would just be taking the highest one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gotta remember vectors can be negative, so the assumption that `+` would always yield a larger result than max in aggregation is wrong. Changing the code to:

```
FinalColor = clamp(FinalColor + max(vec3(0,0,0), DiffuseColor.rgb * Intensity), vec3(0,0,0), vec3(1,1,1));
```

Yields a result similar to max;